# How much time do you have to fix a typo in a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing-help

If you ask a question that has a typo, how much time do you have to edit the typo before an answer invalidates your edit?

Timeline:

```
T=0      Question is asked with a typo.
T=2 min  Answer related to the typo happened
T=4 min  Typo is fixed by op
```

The question is now closed as a typo. But I do believe that the edit was not an evolution of the question, but fix and information that were asked by users.

I don't know if it's visible, but early comment now clean activity of the post show that the OP was busy answering the question that delay is the first edit.

Comment: Well, it's tempting to say that you can't fix it once you have an answer, but consider what that would mean. The asker would have to post a new question with the typo corrected, and the old typo question would just be closed and eventually deleted because it's unhelpful to anyone else. Deletion of the typo question would take the answer about the typo with it, so we really didn't accomplish anything by contorting ourselves to preserve that answer. Maybe we should just let the question be edited, delete the unhelpful answer discussing the typo, and go from there.

Comment: As I recall, there is a flag situation to close questions whose problems are solved only by fixing a typo. It is under _should be closed -> off topic because_, if I recall correctly...

Comment: When faced with this, I just keep the original question too. Either as a PS that original question was or rewrite the corrected part as an EDIT. It keeps enough context for all answers for future readers and also doesn't create dupes

Comment: @CodyGray I don't believe the first answer should be deleted, both answers can stay - perhaps the original error could be added, clearly the accepted answer solved the error, but the first answer also pointed out another issue.

Comment: Is it just me or is this sentence incomprehensible? *early comment now clean activity of the post show that the OP was busy answering the question that delay is the first edit*

Comment: Maybe this is a little beside the point, but _don't type your code into the question_, and this will be much less likely to happen to begin with. Create a [mcve] in your dev environment, and copy that exact code into the question. Then, whatever problems the code in your question has will be the same problems your actual code has.

Comment: Oh, I guess [mcve] doesn't work here? I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Copy pasting the code would have been a great solution but i will be here talking about geting bad for insulting my compiler with french insult. Because I was a bit frustrate by the 'bug'

Comment: @Drag yeah, I know it isn't always possible, just a best case scenario.

Comment: It took me 1 years too cool my head enought to make sure I will be nice. The Typo is the original question is just in the question and not in my code. I took two minute to fix it in the question when I was aware of it. Fixing this typo does not solve the issue. The answer is unrelated to the question As I notified as soon as I got the answer. May this be reopen? Or completly delete(not dissociate...).

Answer (score 10):

It's not about how long you have, it's about whether or not the solution to the question, as originally asked, was the typo.  If fixing the typo fixes the problem described in the question, then the solution to the problem is fixing the typo, and the problem should just be closed (and not answered in the first place).  Editing the question into a completely different question, just because you've found the answer to your question, isn't appropriate; this is true regardless of how long it's been since the question was asked.

If the typo is irrelevant to the problem, and fixing it does not solve the problem described or answer the question asked, then any answers suggesting fixing the typos are simply incorrect answers that don't answer the question.  They're just posts that ought to have been comment suggesting how the question could be improved without actually being an answer to the question.  (Whether they meet the criteria for NAA would depend on whether the answerer realizes they don't answer the question or not; if they acknowledge that this doesn't answer the question, and that they're just pointing out an unrelated typo, then the answer merits flagging as NAA.)  In this case it's entirely appropriate for the author to edit the question to fix the typo, as it's simply noise to leave it in and detracts from the actual question; this is true regardless of how long it's been since the question was asked or what answers may or may not mention it.

None of this is at all dependant on timing.

Comment: The case is borderline because the original error op talked about was the infamous `CS0103` know as _"The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current context "_ that indicate a Typo. So saying it's a typo can be seen as a typo, so you only have Op word that it's not the solution

Comment: @DragandDrop If the question doesn't contain enough information to reliably reproduce the described problem, then the question merits closure for *that* reason, and should have been closed as such.  So if that question doesn't contain enough information to be able to know what the problem was, or how to fix it, then close the question for *that* reason, rather than closing it as a typo because you think it might be a typo (without even being able to tell if it's actually a typo).  Thus you never need to rely on the OP's word as to what the solution to the problem actually was.